# Tried p + scale_fill_discrete(name = "New Legend Title") but legend title still not changing

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, mixed-models

I combined two plots of predicted mixed effect model and trying to change the legend title "sR" so that it is friendly to read but I couldn't get it to work when using p + scale_fill_discrete(name = "New Legend Title"). I believe it should be a simple fix but still scratching my head why I can't get it to work even after reading other posts in stackoverflow. Can someone help me please? Thanks.

Below is my R code for you to reproduce the problem:

```
library(nlme)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggeffects)

#For lowW dataset:

SurfaceCoverage <- c(0.04,0.08,0.1,0.12,0.15,0.2,0.04,0.08,0.1,0.12,0.15,0.2)
TotalSurfaceEnergy <- c(139.31449,105.17776,105.38411,99.27608,92.29064,91.55114,84.44251,78.40453,74.66656,73.33242,72.42429,77.08666)
sample <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)

lowW <- data.frame(sample,SurfaceCoverage,TotalSurfaceEnergy)

lowW$sample <- sub("^", "Wettable", lowW$sample)
lowW$RelativeHumidity <- "Low relative humidity"; lowW$group <- "Wettable"
lowW$sR <- paste(lowW$sample,lowW$RelativeHumidity)

dflowW <- data.frame(
  "y"=c(lowW$TotalSurfaceEnergy),
  "x"=c(lowW$SurfaceCoverage),
  "b"=c(lowW$sample),
  "sR"=c(lowW$sR)
)

mixed.lme <- lme(y~log(x),random=~1|b,data=dflowW)
pred.mmlowW <- ggpredict(mixed.lme, terms = c("x"))

#For highW dataset: 
  
SurfaceCoverage <- c(0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.1,0.12,0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.1,0.12)
TotalSurfaceEnergy <- c(66.79554,61.46907,57.56855,54.00953,54.28361,55.15855,50.72314,48.55892,47.41811,43.70885,42.13757,40.55924)
sample <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)

highW <- data.frame(sample,SurfaceCoverage,TotalSurfaceEnergy)

highW$sample <- sub("^", "Wettable", highW$sample)
highW$RelativeHumidity <- "High relative humidity"; highW$group <- "Wettable"
highW$sR <- paste(highW$sample,highW$RelativeHumidity)

dfhighW <- data.frame(
  "y"=c(highW$TotalSurfaceEnergy),
  "x"=c(highW$SurfaceCoverage),
  "b"=c(highW$sample),
  "sR"=c(highW$sR)
)

mixed.lme <- lme(y~log(x),random=~1|b,data=dfhighW)
pred.mmhighW <- ggpredict(mixed.lme, terms = c("x"))

# Combine two predicted mixed effect model into a single ggplot:

p <- ggplot() +
  #lowa plot
  geom_line(data=pred.mmlowW, aes(x = x, y = predicted)) +          # slope
  geom_ribbon(data=pred.mmlowW, aes(x = x, ymin = predicted - std.error, ymax = predicted + std.error), 
              fill = "lightgrey", alpha = 0.5) +  # error band
  geom_point(data = dflowW,                      # adding the raw data (scaled values)
             aes(x = x, y = y, shape = sR)) + 
  
  #higha plot
  geom_line(data=pred.mmhighW, aes(x = x, y = predicted)) +          # slope
  geom_ribbon(data=pred.mmhighW, aes(x = x, ymin = predicted - std.error, ymax = predicted + std.error), 
              fill = "lightgrey", alpha = 0.5) +  # error band
  geom_point(data = dfhighW,                      # adding the raw data (scaled values)
             aes(x = x, y = y, shape = sR)) + 
  xlim(0.01,0.2) + 
  ylim(30,150) +
  labs(title = "") + 
  ylab(bquote('Total Surface Energy ' (mJ/m^2))) +
  xlab(bquote('Surface Coverage ' (n/n[m]) )) +
  theme_minimal()

print(p)

p1 <- p + scale_fill_discrete(name = "New Legend Title")

print(p1)
```

[image]

Comment: You e printed `p`, not `p1` and used `scale_fill_discrete` when the aesthetic you want to map is a shape. Use `scale_shape_discrete` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much @Limey. I have added another line print(p1) in my post. Will you be able to also help me on how to order the symbol so that it goes with the order of triangle, +, circle and square?

Comment: `scale_shape_manual(values=c(17, 3, 16, 15))`.  See the final example in the online doc for `ggplot2::scale_shape` for one way to get a list of shapes and their corresponding values.

Comment: Someone leads me to a post with the relevant answer and I got it fixed. The R code is p1 <- p + 
  scale_shape_discrete(name = "New Legend Title",
                       breaks=c("Wettable1 Low relative humidity","Wettable2 Low relative humidity",
                                "Wettable1 High relative humidity","Wettable2 High relative humidity")
                       )